# Figure captions enumerated vertically

Tags: floats, subcaption

I found solution for placing 6 figures like this:

```
a   b   c

d   e   f
```

Now I want to arrange figures like this:

```
a   c   e

b    d   f
```

How to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you can place your figures as the first pattern, you can modify the order of them and have the correct result (d1 -> b2, b1 -> c2, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of tabular environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.3\hsize}@{}}
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{A}
    \label{A}
\end{subfigure}                     \\
    \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
         \caption{B}
        \label{B}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.3\hsize}@{}}
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{C}
    \label{C}
\end{subfigure}                     \\
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{D}
    \label{D}
\end{subfigure}%
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.3\hsize}@{}}
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{E}
    \label{F}
\end{subfigure}                     \\
    \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
        \caption{E}
        \label{E}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Value}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```